# Excel - Add Own Macro to "Right Click" in Selected Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to add an option to the "right click" menu and attach a macro to that option.  Ideally I would like this option to only show on one worksheet, called "main", and only in cells "C21:C42".

For the purpose of this example I am happy if all the macro does is:

```
msgbox "Hello World"
```

Many thanks in advance, Alan.

Comment: OP, https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4375-excel-add-button-macro-to-right-click-menu.html is what you are looking for, correct?

Comment: @zedfoxus - no attempt made. This is not a code-writing service. Questions asking "I would like" without showing any effort tend to be rather poorly received here.

Comment: @BigBen I understand. That's a fair assessment. It could help the OP if we gave them an explanation and chance to update their question with what they tried or searched online.

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback @BigBen,

It is hard to please everyone.  Previously when I have put additional information in I have been told not to include it as it is wasted time for people to read.  I was asked to be more succinct.

As for the 10+ suggesting a pattern I have not asked for feedback previously but felt this question was clear and concise so thought I would ask.  Going forward I will include what I have tried, but I am sure someone else will find that equally as offensive.

Comment: @AlanTingey - the best you can do is to follow this site's guidelines at [ask] and [reprex]. But the link provided by zedfoxus should get you started.

Comment: Many thanks, I will reread the How to Ask and hopefully asked more relevant questions ongoing.  Appreciate both your feedback.  As for the link provided that is the link I am currently trying to use BUT can only get it working everywhere and I am struggling to get it running on just one worksheet only let alone a specific range.  Maybe it is best if I delete the question and rewrite a new one?

Comment: In the `Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)` code check the `Sh` reference (sheet reference) to make sure the correct sheet is active before adding the menu item.

Comment: ^^^ Also use `Intersect` to check if `Target` overlaps with the range in question. You can always [edit] your question with your current code attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, copy the next code **in the sheet module where you want it acting**.

**Edited**:

It now passes a parameter (param):

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim cmdBtn As CommandBarButton, param As String
  
  Set cmdBtn = Application.CommandBars("Cell").FindControl(, , "testBt")
  If Intersect(Target, Range("C21:C42")) Is Nothing Then
    If Not cmdBtn Is Nothing Then cmdBtn.Delete
    Exit Sub
  End If
    
    If Not cmdBtn Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set cmdBtn = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True)
    param = "TesParam" 'parameter to be sent. It can be any kind...
    With cmdBtn
        .Tag = "testBt"
        .Caption = "MyOption"
        .Style = msoButtonCaption
        .OnAction = "'TestMacro """ & param & """'"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Dim cmdBtn As CommandBarButton
    Set cmdBtn = Application.CommandBars("Cell").FindControl(, , "testBt")
    If Not cmdBtn Is Nothing Then cmdBtn.Delete
End Sub
```

You need a "TestMacro" Sub in a standard module.

```
Sub TestMacro(str As String)
   MsgBox "It works... (" & str & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Alan Tingey: Did you find some time to test the suggested answer? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: Hello there, just found some time and had success with the example.  My current challenge is passing a variable to the sub as this will be required in the final version.  Any thoughts? or maybe a new question is required?

Comment: @Alan Tingey: It doesn't look so complicated... But, as you said, asking another question is the right way. Copy the above code and clearly state what variable yould you like passing.  If you tag me (@FaneDuru) here, after placing the question, I will try helping. If not available, somebody else will do it

Comment: Many thanks for the tip but think I have found a solution for anyone looking in the future:

.OnAction = "=gotoUPC(" & currentUPC & ")"

Comment: @Alan Tingey: I will adapt the above code with a different way to pass a parameter... Did it.

Comment: Many thanks for that, amazing!  Just tagged in the follow up questions regards changing worksheet,  Hopefully the tag worked?

Comment: @Alan Tingey:  I'm afraid I cannot get you... Did you tag me as user somewhere? Are you talking about the control/button tag, or waht?